# How to map two entity to one with automapper?

Tags: automapper

I have three entity.

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class Author
{
    public string AuthorName {get;set;}
}

public class BookDTO
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string AuthorName {get;set;}
}
```

how to map `Book` and `Author` to `BookDTO` ?
and how to map `BookDTO` to `Book` and `Author`?
I used the automapper in my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a mapping for each:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Author, BookDTO>();
```

And then use it like this:

```cs
Book b = new Book { Name = "Gulliver's Travels" };
Author a = new Author { AuthorName = "Jonathan Swift" };

var dto = Mapper.Map<Book, BookDTO>(b);

Mapper.Map<Author, BookDTO>(a, dto);
```